# How to pull nginx from docker and run it only in python script

Tags: python, docker, nginx

I'm trying to pull nginx from docker hub using python docker library.
After pulling the nginx i want to run it and configure it 
to test some RestAPI requests - only basic ones to get response (200 OK).

What i already have is the following:

```
img = client.images.pull('nginx:latest')
client.containers.run(img, detach=True)
```

After these lines i can see the new docker in the list got here:

```
client.containers.list()
```

currently there is nothing happened, got nothing in http://localhost:8080.
what do i missed?
how to configure this nginx in the docker with the python library?

**Update and more info:**
The solution of the port was very helpful.
Now i can send GET request and get a response with "200 OK" 
But now when i'm trying to send POST request i got "405 Not Allowed". 
In a quick search in google i found that i need to configure nginx.config 
in this way:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404     /404.html;
    error_page  403     /403.html;

    # To allow POST on static pages
    error_page  405     =200 $uri;

    # ...
}
```

My question now is how can i config this file with the docker API?
Is this the right solution? replace 405 with 200??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port binding need to be set. Try the following command:

```
client.containers.run(img, detach=True, ports={'80/tcp': 8080})
```

The `ports` parameter tells the Docker Daemon to expose port 80 inside the Nginx container as port 8080 on the host.

I recommend you going through the API reference first: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html

Comment: I have a question I am trying to tag my image container and then push it to my docker hub , can you help me out? as I struggled to find a solution via documentation for the API

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the port mapping during containers.run() setting.